# Prediction without data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have to do data analysis on the data of a machine in order to improve performance. The problem is that the data shows a conservative behavior of the machine. In other words, the machine is always performing at 70% of its capacity, and everything is always ok. But to improve performance, it is necessary to increase its capacity, but I don't know how the machine will work because I don't have this data. I am wondering what statistical or machine learning model should I use to predict something that I don't have the data?

Comment: Do you have data for something *like* the machine you are studying? Can you think of any analogous process that is similar that has evidence of higher performance?  If either is possible, then, yes, there are ways to extrapolate from your 70% performance data with the augmented performance of similar systems to predict (with a relatively large margin for error) the performance of your system under untested conditions, given that nothing "unpredictable happens," viz., it blows up, or something.

Answer (score 2):

Without having data, you're going to have to make assumptions. These assumptions may or may not be reasonable to someone who understands the machinery - talking with a subject matter expert may help here!

A couple of possible assumptions:

1. Extrapolation: if there's a, for example, linear trend between capacity and performance, you can extrapolate this trend to capacity levels you haven't observed. Example (dashed line is the prediction):

[image]

2. You have another similar, but not exactly the same, machine: if the machine you're interested in (call it Machine A) is similar to another machine (call it Machine B), you can use that information. Say Machine B has a certain relationship between capacity and performance and you observe this relationship for capacity values beyond 70%. If Machine A looks similar for capacity values below 70%, a possible assumption is that it'll continue to similar to Machine B. Example (dashed line is the prediction):

[image]

3. Survival analysis: if you have many machines that have been used to capacity values beyond 70%, surely some have failed. The ones that haven't failed, would eventually fail if taken to higher capacity levels - they just haven't yet. This is known as right-censored data which can be analyzed using something called survival analysis. With survival analysis, you can even use features of the machine to help your predictions. For example, size, weight, wattage, etc.

Comment: Extrapolation is risky in such cases. What if the machine breaks after exceeding 70%? Extrapolation would "work" even when asking about 100%, or 300% capacity with no indication how wrong it could be.

Comment: @Tim Agreed! But since we have no data, we've got to make some assumptions. My advice is to talk to SMEs to figure out some reasonable assumptions.